# How to register an interrupt handler for x2APIC generated IPI?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, apic

I have enabled the `x2APIC` on the host OS and want to generate the IPI at the host level itself(and not inside a VM).

To check if x2APIC is enabled or not, I run the following command:

```
sudo rdmsr 0x1b // IA32_APIC_BASE MSR to check the x2APIC status
```

And according to Intel SDM bit 10 shows the `x2APIC` status. The result for the above command is - `fee00d00` and `d-1101`. So, both bit 10 and 11 are enabled, which means that LAPIC can work in both APIC and x2APIC mode.

After enabling this, I am trying to write an interrupt handler so that I can handle the IPI generated by the lapic.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("A-B");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple example Linux module.");
MODULE_VERSION("0.01");

#define IRQ_x2APIC 0xf0  //Taken from the reserved linux list

#define APIC_EOI_MSR 0x80B
#define EOI_ACK 0x0

#define wrmsrl(msr, val) \
    write_msr((msr), (u32)((u64)(val)), (u32)((u64)(val) >> 32))


static inline void write_msr(unsigned int msr, unsigned low, unsigned high)
{
   asm volatile("wrmsr" : : "c" (msr), "a"(low), "d" (high) : "memory");
}


static irqreturn_t handler_irq(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
    printk("irq %d\n", irq);
    wrmsrl(APIC_EOI_MSR, EOI_ACK);
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static void register_handler(unsigned int irq) {
    const char *devname = "x2apic_irq";
    int ret = request_irq(irq, (irq_handler_t )handler_irq, IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING |  IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING | IRQF_PERCPU, devname, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "request_irq failed with %d\n", ret);
    }
}

static int __init lkm_example_init(void) {
    free_irq(IRQ_x2APIC, NULL);
    register_handler(IRQ_x2APIC);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit lkm_example_exit(void) {
    free_irq(IRQ_x2APIC, NULL);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye, World!\n");
}

module_init(lkm_example_init);
module_exit(lkm_example_exit);
```

After loading this module using `insmod`, I hope to see an entry in `/proc/interrupts` but I get the error message `request_irq failed with -22`(Invalid Arguments) when I run `dmesg` command.

Could you please point out, what is wrong with the module? Or What else do I need to do to register the interrupt handler?

Comment: Linux has its own IPI handlers. Why are you trying to install your own?  Also the ICR is the Interrupt Command Register.  It's used to send IPIs by writing a suitable value to it. In x2APIC mode it doesn't have a defined value when read, but it practice it should be contain the last value written to it. That means the ICR register just contains the value the kernel last used to send an IPI. Also note that the interrupt vector number used with the ICR isn't an interrupt line number.

Comment: @RossRidge I am writing a PoC for fast preemption as done in https://www.usenix.org/conference/nsdi19/presentation/kaffes but at the host level.

Writing to ICR is generating an IPI and I can see it in `dmesg.`

The only part I am not sure about is, how to write a custom handler. And I thought that `request_irq` will help me there.

Comment: I suspect (based on the parameters) that `request_irq()` is for IRQs (e.g. devices wired up to one of the IO APIC inputs) and not for "interrupts that are not IRQs" (e.g. IPIs, exceptions, software interrupts).

Comment: I also generated an IPI on the IRQ line(129-238) using `sudo wrmsr 0x830 0x0000000000000082` and got the `do_IRQ: 0.130 No irq handler for vector` is dmesg output. 

I am not sure if its the right thing to do, but I was thinking of generating an IPI on a IRQ line and handle it using a custom handler.

Comment: Vector 0xF0 is reserved for KVM-related IPI in the latest Linux kernel sources.  To create a new IPI vector you'll need to edit the kernel sources and recompile as they're all statically allocated. With the current kernel sources it looks like you'd want to edit arch/x86/include/asm/irq_vectors.h, lowering the value of LOCAL_TIMER_VECTOR by 1 and then using its old value as your custom IPI vector. Then add a BUILD_INTERRUPT line to linux/arch/x86/include/asm/entry_arch.h.

Comment: If you only need it work on the machine you're using now that could work. Otherwise the mapping between interrupt lines and interrupt vectors isn't predictable and I believe can even change between CPUs.

Comment: @A-B: You're using "unusual terminology". Typically when it's on some kind of device bus (ISA, PCI) it's an IRQ and has an IRQ number (e.g. "IRQ 1 on legacy/ISA bus"); but this is translated by an interrupt controller into an "interrupt vector" (e.g. IRQ 1 on legacy/ISA bus" might be translated by IO APIC into "interrupt vector 99"). IPIs are not IRQs, they don't have IRQ numbers, there's no translation from "IRQ number" to "interrupt vector", and you provide the "interrupt vector" directly in the IPI.